# Is there a way to return the max value of column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table...

```
name | day | showers
-----|-----|--------
John | mon | 1
John | tue | 2
John | wed | 1
Pete | fri | 3
```

and I want to return the table of each persons day with the most showers...

```
name | day | showers
-----|-----|--------
John | tue | 2
Pete | fri | 3
```

How would I do this?

I thought I could do...

```
SELECT name, day FROM table GROUP BY name WHERE showers=max(showers)
```

but I get a syntax error due to day not being in the group by clause

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Comment: if theres a tie it should name the person twice for each day tied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `uncorrelated subquery`. This will keep the ties as well

```
select *
from t 
where (name, showers) in (select name, max(showers)
                          from t
                          group by name);
```

Can also be expressed as a `correlated subquery`

```
select *
from t t1
where showers= (select max(t2.showers)
                from t t2
                where t1.name=t2.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name, showers desc;
```

This returns exactly one row per name.  If you want duplicates if there are ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by name order by showers desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT name, days, showers
FROM test
WHERE showers =
(SELECT max(showers) FROM test i WHERE i.name = test.name)
```

A correlated subquery is one way of reading every row in a table and comparing values in each row against related data. It is used whenever a subquery must return a different result or set of results for each candidate row considered by the main query. In other words, you can use a correlated subquery to answer a multipart question whose answer depends on the value in each row processed by the parent statement.

[image: So from the original table][image: you get this result]

So from the original table on the left, by running this query, you get the result in the table on the right